# aws ec2 us-east-2 is an invalid region choice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have created a new instance on us-east-2, configured the security groups, policies and access rules and I can see it running and access it via the browser. However, when I attempt to connect to it via the aws-cli, it tells me us-east-2 is an invalid choice for the region.

What am I missing here? It is clearly a region on AWS: [image]

I am running Ubuntu and `aws --version` results in: aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.3 Linux/3.13.0-100-generic

I am trying to connect to the instance via `aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id XXXXXXXX --region us-east-2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CLI version is outdated by 3 years and it doesn't know the new regions. Can you upgrade the CLI to **1.10.x** and try?

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.10.66 Python/2.7.12 Linux/3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.4.56

$ aws ec2 describe-regions
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "us-east-2"
        },
```

Comment: Sigh, that's what I get for trusting the package manager and update. I will give this a shot tonight and let you know. Thanks